# Inotify-like feature in a distributed file system

Tags: hdfs, publish-subscribe, nfs, inotify, distributed-filesystem

As the title goes, I want to trigger a notification when some events happen.

A event above can be user-defined, such as `updating specified files in 1-miniute`.

If files are stored locally, I can easily make it with the system call `inotify`, but the case is that files locate on a distributed file system such as mfs..

How to make it? I wonder to know if there are some solutions or open-source project to solve this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you have only black-box access (e.g. NFS protocol) to the remote system(s), you don't have much options unless the protocol supports what you need.  So I'll assume you have control over the remote systems.

The "trivial" approach is running a local inotify/fanotify listener on each computer that would forward the notification over the network.  [FAM can do this over NFS](http://oss.sgi.com/projects/fam/faq.html#network_mode).

A problem with all notification-based system is the risk of lost notifications in various edge cases.  This becomes much more acute over a network - e.g. client confirms reciept of notification, then immediately crashes.  There are reliable message queues you can build on but IMHO this way lies madness...

### A saner approach is *stateless hash-based* scan.

I like to call the following design "hnotify" but that's not an established term.  The ideas are widely used by many version control and backup systems, dating back to [Plan 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venti).

The core idea is if you know cryptographic hashes for files, you can compose a single hash that represents a directory of files - it changes if *any* of the files changed - and you can build these bottom-up to represent *the whole filesystem's state*.
([Git stores things this way](http://www.gitguys.com/topics/git-object-tree/) and is very efficient at it.)

Why are hash trees cool?  If you have 2 hash trees — one representing the filesystem state you saw at point in the past, one representing the current state — you can easily find out what changed between them:

1. You start at the roots.  If they are different you read the 2 root directories and compare hashes for subdirectories.
2. If a subdirectory has same hash in both trees, then *nothing* under it changed.  No point going there.
3. If a subdirectory's hash changed, compare its contents recursively — call step (1).
4. If one has a subdirectory the other doesn't, well that's a change.  With some global table you can also detect moves/renames.

Note that if few files changed, you only read a small portion of the current state.  So the remote system doesn't have to send you the whole tree of hashes, it can be an interactive ping-pong of "give me hashes for this directory; ok now for this...".
(This is akin to how Git's dumb http protocol [worked; there is a newer](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols) protocol with less round trips.)

This is as robust and bug-proof as polling the whole filesystem for changes — you can't miss anything — but reasonably efficient!

#### But how does the server track current hashes?

Unfortunately, fully hashing all disk writes is too expensive for most people.  You may get if for free if you're lucky to be running a deduplicating filesystem, e.g. ZFS or Btrfs.
Otherwise you're stuck with re-reading all changed files (which is even more expensive than doing it in the filesystem layer) or using *fake file hashes*: upon any change to a file, invent a new random "hash" to invalidate it (and try to keep the fake hashes on moves).  Still compute real hashes up the tree.  Now you may have false positives — you "detect a change" when the content is the same — but never false negatives.

Anyway, the point is that whatever stateful hacks you do (e.g. inotify with periodic scans to be sure), you only do them *locally on the server*.  Across the network, you only ever send hashes that represent snapshots of current state (or its subtrees)!  This way you can have a distributed system with many servers and clients, intermittent connectivity, and still keep your sanity.

P.S. Btrfs can [efficiently find differences from an older snapshot](http://www.tummy.com/blogs/2010/11/01/fun-with-btrfs-what-files-have-changed/).  But this is a snapshot taken on the server (and causing all data to be preserved!), less flexible than a client-side lightweight tree-of-hashes.

P.S. One of your tags is HadoopFS.  I'm not really familiar with it, but I suspect a lot of its files are write-once-then-immutable, and it might be able to natively give you some kind of file/chunk ids that can serve as fake hashes?

#### Existing tools

- The first tool that springs to my mind is `bup index`.  [bup](https://github.com/bup/bup) is a very clever deduplicating backup tool built on git (only scalable to huge data), so it sits on the foundation described above.  In theory, indexing data in bup on the server and doing `git fetch` over the network would even implement the hash-walking comparison of what's new that I described above — unfortunately the git repositories that bup produces are too big for git itself to cope with.  Also you probably don't want bup to read and store all your data.  But `bup index` is a separate subsystem that quickly scans a filesystem for potential changes, without yet reading the changed files.
  Currently bup doesn't use inotify but it's been [discussed in depth](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/bup-list/CXRI7MS3LwM).

  Oh, and bup uses Bloom Filters which are a nearly optimal way to represent sets with false positives.  I'm almost certain Bloom filters have a role to play in optimizion stateless notification protocols ("here is a compressed bitmap of all I have; you should be able to narrow your queries with it" or "here is a compressed bitmap of what I want to be notified about").  Not sure if [the way bup uses them](https://github.com/bup/bup/blob/master/DESIGN#L284) is directly useful to you, but this data structure should definitely be in your toolbelt.
- Another tool is [git annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/).  It's also based on Git (are you noticing a trend?) but is designed to keep the data itself out of Git repos (so `git fetch` should just work!) and has a ["WORM" option](http://git-annex.branchable.com/backends/) that uses fake hashes for faster performance.

### Alternative design: compressed replayable journal

I used to think the above is the only sane stateless approach for clients to check what's changed.  But I just read http://arstechnica.com/apple/2007/10/mac-os-x-10-5/7/ about OS X's FSEvents framework, which has a perhaps simpler design:

- ALL changes are logged to a file.  It's kept forever.
- Clients can ask "replay for me everything since event 51348".
- The magic trick is the log has coarse granularity ("something in this directory changed, go re-scan it to find out what", repeated changes within 30 seconds are combined) so this  journal file is very compact.

At the low level you might resort to similar techniques — e.g. hashes — but the top-level interface is different: instead of snapshots you deal with a timeline of events.  It may be an easier fit for some applications.